# Interpret Delete Key from Number Pad in a Edit Did Change Event

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am trying to capture when a user presses the del key on a number pad on an iPhone in a Edit Did Change event.  I presume I can capture it through the sender event but can not find the object to grab and have looked on the net but can not find anywhere where I can get the key pressed through the sender event.

I am making a phone number text field formatter and would like to allow the user to use the del key to delete the "-"'s.  But now the way it is written of course it stops there.  I just need to capture the del key and have it ignore the formatting.

Thoughts?

```
  - (IBAction)homePhoneEditChanged:(id)sender 
  {
      if(homePhone.text.length == 13)
      {
          homePhone.text = [homePhone.text substringToIndex:12];
          return;
      }

      static BOOL toggle = NO;
      if (toggle) 
      {
           toggle = NO;
          return;
      }
      // Add a condition here to ignore if the del key was pressed
      if( homePhone.text.length == 3 || homePhone.text.length == 7)
      {
          // Add a -
          toggle = YES;
          homePhone.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",homePhone.text];
      }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone number formatting is a fairly complex idea if you're going to be concerned with localization.  Would it be better to restrict the field to a number only field and then follow something like [this](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html)?

Comment: Thank you the the info, however, I have a specific need and do not really need to consider local in this application.  I really just need to understand how to capture the del key when pressed within this method.  I will keep this link for future consideration though and truly appreciate your help!

Comment: NP.  This is not an easy problem to solve while following Apple Guidelines.  Someone here, http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2012/01/catching-keyboard-events-in-ios.html has figured out a hack.  Good luck.  I don't know if this would work for external keyboards, though.